# Spring XD 1.2.0+ Custom Module Deployment

Tags: spring, spring-xd

Has something changed with the way custom modules should be deployed in Spring XD 1.2.0?

I have a development singlenode installed on windows. I have the XD_CONFIG_LOCATION enviroment variable set up to point to my servers.yml configuration file and within this I have xd.customModule.home configured to point to an external directory for modules.

Up to version 1.1.3 anything in here was visible by the shell 'module list' command or in the UI, however since 1.2.0 my custom modules no longer show up by just placing them in the directory. Instead I have to use the 'module upload' command to install the modules (which also seems to generate an md5 file in the custom module directory). Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in 1.2.0 we introduced support for creating a module registry in hdfs. Along with this, an md5 file is created during `module upload` primarily to protect against using a module before the upload is complete. We recognize this is a potential issue for those upgrading to 1.2.x with an existing custom module registry. See [XD-3321](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-3321).

Meanwhile, you can try `md5 -q mymodule.jar > mymodule.jar.md5`